# How can I take multiple fighting styles?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighting-style

For a fighter in D&D 5e, I can take one fighting style as part of the character creation. At third level, I can choose a martial archetype (Champion) which will later (at 10th level) allow me to choose an additional fighting style.

Is there any **other** way to choose multiple fighting styles?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Yes, if multiclassing is allowed.**

You can take 2 levels of Paladin to gain an additional fighting style, and/or 2 levels of Ranger to gain another.

> **James** @JamesMusicus
>   @JeremyECrawford Hi Jeremy, I was wondering about the wording of Fighting Styles in 5e. Can you have more than 1 from multiclassing?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford
>   Yep!
>   [2:22 AM - 21 Jan 2015](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/557815371647164419?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2015%2F01%2F23%2Fmulticlass-fighting-styles%2F)

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding that the only other restriction is that you cannot take the *same* Fighting Style more than once.

Answer (score 15):

#### Fighting Initiate

In addition to multiclassing or being a 10th level Champion Fighter, *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* introduced a feat that allows you to choose a fighting style, [Fighting Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/fighting-initiate):

> Your martial training has helped you develop a particular style of fighting. As a result, you learn one Fighting Style option of your choice from the fighter class. If you already have a style, the one you choose must be different.

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding that the only other restriction is that you cannot take the *same* Fighting Style more than once.

Comment: "If you already have a style, the one you choose must be different." is right there in the answer.

Answer (score -24):

For ALL intents and purposes for fighting styles; Fighter, Paladin, and Ranger included....there is this bit on the end:

> PHB pg72, pg84, pg91 **Fighting Styles**:  *"...You CAN'T take a Fighting Style option more than once, even if you later get to choose again..."*

Since the only way you would ever be able TO choose more than once is through multiclassing, this is a down the board hard rule and includes but is not limited to Multiclassing.
The ONLY addendum to this rule is when it specifically states in your class list that you may choose another from the list, as with hitting Champion level 10.

Comment: I think this text is suggesting that you can't take the *same* one more than once, not that you can't take *one* more than once. (several of them would be able to stack, like the ranged +2 to attacks, duelists +1 to damage, armored's +1 to AC etc)

Comment: @waxeagle Hmm....you know what? You may be on to something....but I see potential for abuse if the text isn't ruled the way I personally interpret it.  Even if you can't stack the SAME one, having 2 (Champion) plus 1 from Paladin/Ranger could still result in some pretty hardcore maxing.  I see your point though.... I wonder if there's any official interpretation on this.  Never thought of it that way.

Comment: honestly, there isn't all the much potential there from where I sit, Defensive+armored+fighting technique is about as good as you can get, which isn't all that great tbh. And, ultimately, martial characters are so far behind casters that it's not really even remotely an issue.