# Do the fighting styles 'Close Quarters Shooter' and 'Archery' Stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking

I am attempting to convert one of my characters from 3.5e to 5e.

In 3.5, my character was a level 15 Wood Elf character was 4 Rng / 5 Wiz / 3 Arcane Archer / 3 Order of the Bow Initiate.

For 5e I kept the race and total level the same and decided on 7 Ranger (Horizon Walker) Archery Fighting style / 8 Fighter (Arcane Archer) Close Quarters Shooting fighting style.

**Would I gain the attack bonus from both of those two fighting styles (+2 from Ranger's Archery and +1 from Fighter's CQS)?**

P.S. - I took Elven Accuracy and Sharpshooter as feats.

Comment: I have made substantial edits to your post, please confirm that the core of the question remains.

Answer (score 18):

### Yes, They stack.

5th edition has a lot fewer additive bonuses than some previous editions, and therefore does not need to prohibit the few circumstances where you get multiple bonuses. The biggest "gotcha" is making sure that you aren't getting the same bonus from two sources (you can't have two castings of Bless active on you, for example).

It is also worth noting that 5e does not have typed bonuses the same way that some other editions did (circumstance, skill, enhancement, etc.). Bonuses are just bonuses. Add 'em up.

Comment: [Relevant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59879/how-can-i-take-multiple-fighting-styles/59881?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)